# Vue JS v-for not iterating over array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi guys I am using Vue JS to try and loop through my data. Here is my whole JS file:

```
var contentful = require('contentful');

var client = contentful.createClient({
  space: 'HIDDEN',
  accessToken: 'HIDDEN'
});

Vue.component('careers', {
  template: '<div><div v-for="career in careerData">{{ fields.jobDescription }}</div></div>',

  data: function() {
    return {
     careerData: []
    }
  },

  created: function() {
   this.fetchData();
  },

  methods: {
   fetchData: function() {
     client.getEntries()
     .then(function (entries) {
       // log the title for all the entries that have it
       entries.items.forEach(function (entry) {
         if(entry.fields.jobTitle) {
           this.careerData = entries.items;
         }
       })
     });
   }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

I am using methods to access some data from Contentful, once it has grabbed the necessary data it is sent to my data object.

If I `console.log(careerData);` within my console the following data is returned:

[image]

So I'd expect if I used `v-for` within my template and tried iterating over `careerData` it would render correctly however on my front-end I am left with an empty div like so:

```
<div id="app"><div></div></div>
```

I am currently pulling my component into my HTML like so:

```
<div id="app">
  <careers></careers>
</div>
```

No errors are displayed within my console, can you think of any reason this might be happening?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: shouldn't the code in your template be `{{ career.fields.jobDescription }}`?

Comment: I think your v-for starts iterating before the data is fetched. You have to wait for fetchData() to complete the callback before iterating through careerData. Perhaps try adding a check if careerData contains anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems I think. As @dfsq said, you should use a arrow function if you want to keep context (`this`).

```
fetchData: function() {
  client.getEntries()
    .then(entries => {
      this.careerData = entries.items
    });
}
```

Then you may replace `{{fields.jobDescription}}` by `{{career.fields.jobDescription}}`, as @unholysheep wrote.

It may work. If it does not, you could add a `this.$forceUpdate();` right after `this.fetchData();`

Comment: Thanks this really helped, I'm confused to why I didn't need to use the foreach anymore. Maybes I need to do a little bit more research on what `then` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function in `forEach` callback so you don't loose context:

```
fetchData: function() {
  client.getEntries()
    .then(entries => {
      this.careerData = entries.items
    });
}
```